# Unable to find User-defined Function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a UDF defined as follows:

```
Create Or Replace Function Minder_Mvp.Sprint4.Get_Customer_Key(Store_Key VARCHAR)
Returns Table (Customer_Key BIGINT)
AS 

'Select Customer_Key From CustomerBrand
Where CustomerBrand.Brand_Key = 1'

;
```

And then I attempt to call it like this:

```
Select Minder_Mvp.Sprint4.Get_Customer_Key('457');
```

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
Unknown user-define function Minder_MVP.SPRINT4.GET_CUSTOMER_KEY
```

Must be something obvious but I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an [user defined table function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-tabular-functions.html):

> A UDTF can be accessed in the **FROM clause** of a query.

```
Select Minder_Mvp.Sprint4.Get_Customer_Key('457');

=>

SELECT *
FROM TABLE(Minder_Mvp.Sprint4.Get_Customer_Key('457')) s;
```

Comment: Thank you. It would be nice if the documentation showed accessing a UDF this way.

Comment: Good news, it is https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-tabular-functions.html